# Glassfish Form Based security get user info

Tags: forms, security, glassfish-3

I configured the GlassFish JDBC realm with form based authentication in my Java EE app so, everything is ok.

But I want to get the user's info (user_id) and I want to keep it in a list during his session. After his session is timed out or a log out occurred, I will remove it from this list.

Should I change the auth method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Java EE security APIs are not rich enough to provide detailed info about the user that is logged-in.

The only thing you can ask for is the name that the user used to login. You can do this via [HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal#getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) or it's alternative [HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

There are a few workarounds:

1. In a Servlet Filter, check if this "list" you talk of is empty and either of the above methods returns a **non null** value. If this condition holds, query your user details manually based on the username and put them into this "list". *(I'm not really sure why you specifically use a list for this, but that aside)*
2. Indeed change the auth method to a **programmatic** variant. This means you build your own form, dialog, or whatever. Then in your backing code (backing bean if using JSF, otherwise a Servlet or whatever) load the user details, and call [HttpServletRequest#login](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with the username from those details. If this call succeeds immediately put your extended user info in your "list" again.
3. (advanced method) Use a custom auth module (e.g. via JASPIC) and let this auth module delegate to code in your application. This application based code then returns the username and roles to the container and simultaneously puts the user details into the HTTP session. The advantage of this method is that you have the user login/load code in one place, and it's also done once. With the JDBC realm the code (query) is in two places and is also done twice.

I suggest trying option 1 or 2 first. If you want to pursue the advanced method, check out http://jdevelopment.nl/open-source/java-ee-kickoff-app for an example.

If it bothers you that Java EE doesn't have an easier and more powerful mechanism to do this out of the box, please consider voting for this issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVAEE_SPEC-9

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my security method to programmatic with Apache Shiro. I think, Shiro is good and more easy to use then most of other implementation.